# How to make CC.NET continue build after failed task?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, xunit.net

I am trying to run a couple of tasks (the [xunit task](https://xunit.net/docs/getting-test-results-in-ccnet), to be precise) on a CruiseControl.NET instance.

If one of these tasks fails, the build is aborted.

**How can I prevent this?** I would like CC.NET to run all tasks, even if some of them fail (they do not depend on one another).

I have tried running my tasks in a parallel task at first, but that would randomly fail with null reference exceptions most of the time (looked like a bug in CC.NET).

Also, I've tried to find something in the [CC.NET config format docs](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html), but wasn't successful there, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the concept of tasks in CCNet. if one fails, stop running following tasks.
Possible solutions :

- set the **successExitCodes** property to include all exit codes, if the number of those is small
- place your tasks in the publisher section. publishers and tasks have the same base type (ITasks), but publishers are designed to run even if a previous one fails

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the exit code in this case is [more or less related to the number of failed tests](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1081), and thus kind of open-ended. I will look into the publishers workaround.

Comment: another option is to make a batch file, call the test exe and ignore the output,
that it will always be green. But what the value of that is, eludes me.
Maybe you have 5 test suites, and you want to run them all, even if the first one failes. In that case you can still use the batch file approach, but place the outcome of the tests in a variable, and when all tests have ran, and an error occured, let the batch file fail

Comment: "But what the value of that is, eludes me." - for a test run, we don't really look at the overall result most of the time; the major point is getting a complete overview of the diagnostic output of failed (and sometimes also of passed) test cases, coupled with the fact that the tests are run automatically, regularly, and in a defined environment based on the latest complete builds. The batch file approach you propose seems quite useful in any case, and if the overall result is interesting your solution of determining it at the end should do just fine - thank you :)